# Re-create an Activity on Theme change

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-lifecycle

**What I Have**

I have one main activity and one activity for settings. The user can move from the main activity to the settings. In the settings activity, the user can select a theme for the app. Now I have one main activity for the app.

When the user selects the theme, I have finished and restarted that activity to reflect changes immediately.

But when the user presses the back button he is taken to the main activity.

**The Problem**

The `onResume()` method is called and not the `onCreate()`. So the `setTheme()` method on the `onCreate()` doesn't also get called. So the theme change is not reflected here. So what should I do to bring the `theme` change in the `main activity`.

I basically need to ensure that the `onCreate()` of the `main activity` is always called when a theme change occurs.

Answer (score 0):

in `onResume()` method call the `recreate()` [recreate link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#recreate())

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ...........
    recreate();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `boolean`:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public boolean toBeRecreated;

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        if (toBeRecreated) { recreate(); }
    }
}
```

Of course you need to set `MainActivity.toBeRecreated = true` when the user changes your theme.

Comment: Tried recreate() on onResume(). I am getting these, Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Comment: Please edit your question with your code and your complete stacktrace.

Comment: Will it work if I use NavUtils.navigateUpfromSameTask() in onBackPressed() in the settings activity? It seems to solve my problem, but I am not sure.

Comment: The activity is over 300 lines in size, so cannot post that. I was mainly getting that on SearchManager initialization.

Comment: Your error report should tell at which line/in which class you are getting stuck.

Comment: Error report points here, SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.hide_search).getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getActivity().getComponentName()));
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);

Comment: So at that point `getActivity` returns `null`. Can't help you further without more information (code, where/when are these lines called, what is this fragment,...). I don't even know if this is related to your original question.